# Check if key:value pair exist in POST

Tags: php, python, ios, http-post, server

I am trying to check if a key and value are defined in a POST, I want to check if the param is there. I am calling it like this in iOS, not that it really matters how I make the post

```
NSString *param = @"hello world";
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"param=%@",param];
NSString *urlString = @"URL";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//...
```

And then I have a php script that return the same value as the param, but now I want to do the same thing in Python, so I will go to the url where my python script is and then it will check that there is a value for param, and if there is return the same value. So how can I do this in python?

Here is the php script if you want it

```
<?php
$response=array();
if(isset($_POST['param'])){
  $response['success'] = true;
  $response['message'] = 'received param = '.$_POST['param'];
}else{
  $response['success'] = false;
  $response['message'] = 'did not receive param';
}
$json = json_enconde($response);
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is pure Python. I suggest you to go for Django for use of Python in Web domain.

```
import cgi
import json

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

param = form.getvalue("param")

if param:
    json.dumps({'success': True, 'message':  param })
else:
    json.dumps({'success': False, 'message':  'did not receive parameter' })
```

Comment: what do you mean go for django?, also from the permission is `0644` good?

Comment: Python is a General purpose language. It is powerful language across different domain. But in Web domain using pure Python could be complex. That is why I suggest you to go for a Django.  Django is a Python Web Framework.

Comment: okay, so what do i need to do or can I just put the above code in a file and call it `test.py`? cause right now its not working

Comment: Of course not. You need a web server that supports python. https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServers   As I said go for Django which has inbuilt server. It is a breeze in django.

Comment: Okay so the server I am using right now I can run python scripts using cron jobs, so wouldn't it support python then? And the link you posted I go to that page I don't see Django?

Comment: okay thanks if I don't have root access to my server, is there a way to still use django?, why do I need django for this?